# emberjs and electron app

Tags: ember.js, electron

My Electron App is crashed, when i use Ember. The App binds a Web Application and the Web Application has now EmberJS for the Frontend. In the Console is the following error:
[image]

Anybody a idea why this came?

My package.json in electron App have the following dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
"electron-packager": "5.2.1",
"electron-prebuilt": "0.36.10",
"ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
"ember-bootstrap": "0.6.3",
"ember-browserify": "1.1.8",
"ember-cli": "2.10.0",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
"ember-cli-font-awesome": "1.5.0",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.10",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.3",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^3.0.1",
"ember-cli-release": "0.2.9",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
"ember-data": "^2.10.0",
"ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
"ember-electron": "1.12.0",
"ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
"ember-inspector": "1.9.5",
"ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
"ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
"loader.js": "^4.0.10"
}
```

Comment: include jquery in `bower.json`  for `Bootstrap Javascript requires jquery` error. and include `app.import('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');` in ember-cli-build.js file

Comment: JQuery is already included in the ember-cli-build.js and in bower.json...

Comment: In ember-cli-build.js, order is important so keep `jquery` before `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Yes, this is also so.

Comment: I think the Problem is the ember modules system. Unfortunately this is only a guess...

Comment: then you might try https://www.npmjs.com/package/nombom step check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/254

Thank you @kumkanillam for your help. :)